# Easiest way to solve $2^{\sin^2x}-2^{\cos^2x}=\cos 2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, trigonometry

I'm trying to find best shortcut to crack this task

> $$2^{\sin^2x}-2^{\cos^2x}=\cos 2x$$

I tried first to go through using trigonometric identities 
$$\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1 \quad\text{and}\quad 2\sin^2x=1-\cos 2x$$
After substitution I reached this equation
$$2^{1-\cos x}-2^{(1-\cos 2x)/2}\cos 2x -2=0$$
Later, I supposed to use substitution to obtain,
$$u^4-2u^2-2u=0$$

where $u=\sqrt{v}$, $v=\frac{2}{w}$, and $w=\cos 2x$

As a result , I obtained two roots in $\mathbb{R}$ one of them is zero and the other is $1.76929$. This leads me to doubt in my process.

So, is there Hint or procedure can be followed to obtain the desire result?

Comment: Is it not $$2^{\sin^2(x)}+2^{\cos^2(x)}$$

Comment: no Dr , it minus as the author of question mention

Comment: What's the source of the problem?

Answer (score 6):

We have $2^{\sin^2x}+\sin^2x=2^{\cos^2x}+\cos^2x$, so consider the function
$$f(x)=2^x+x$$
which is increasing and continuous then it is one-to-one and therefore $f(\sin^2x)=f(\cos^2x)$ gives us $\sin^2x=\cos^2x$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-You have immediately a solution if you note that for  $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ one has $\sin(x)=\cos(x)$ and $\cos(2x)=0$. The solution is done by $$x=\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}{4};\space\space n\in\mathbb Z$$

Comment: It is obvious that there must be a comma (,) or some words, after $ x = \dfrac {\pi} {4} $.  The first condition is $\sin(x)=\cos(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u:=\cos^2 x$ so $f(u):=2^{1-u}-2^u-2u+1=0=f(\frac12)$. But since $u\in[0,\,1]$, the AM-GM inequality implies $2^{1-u}+2^u\ge 2\sqrt{2}$ and $f^\prime(u)=(2^{1-u}+2^u)\ln 2-2\ge 2(\sqrt{2}-\ln 2)>0$, so $f$ is strictly increasing. The original equation is therefore equivalent to $\cos^2x=\frac12$.